# Работа с пулом процессов приводит к зависанию в Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

Подскажите, как реализовать многопоточность в Jupyter Notebook. Например, я хочу обработать некоторые данные, и записать результат в массив или в файл.

Делаю например так:

```
def test_this(elem, test_list):
    test_list.append(elem)

procs = []
test_list = []
for elem in ["one", "two", "tree"]:
    proc = Process(target=test_this, args=(elem,test_list))
    procs.append(proc)
    proc.start()

for proc in procs:
    proc.join()
```

test_list получается пустой

делаю вот так:

```
with Pool(20) as p:
    p.map(test_this, ["one", "two", "tree"])
```

ячейка зависает навечно.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: полные (но минимальные) примеры кода приведите, которые проблему демонстрируют. К примеру, добавьте импорты. У вас тут две разные проблемы (значение списка в разных процессах и работа с пулом процессов в jupyter). Стоит различать процессы и потоки.

Comment: [на Linux не виснет](https://gist.github.com/zed/bcccd63189d53c544d0ed143c711015c)

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы обойти известные проблемы с `multiprocessing.Pool` в интерактивном случае (таком как работа в jupyter notebook), можно использовать [`multiprocess` модуль](https://pypi.org/project/multiprocess/):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# from multiprocessing import Pool, set_start_method # hangs on Windows and/or with spawn, forkserver methods
from multiprocess import Pool, set_start_method  #! pip install multiprocess

def double(s):
    return s*2

if __name__ == "__main__":
   # set_start_method('fork')  # works
   # set_start_method('spawn') # XXX hangs with stdlib multiprocessing
   # set_start_method('forkserver')  #XXX hangs with stdlib multiprocessing
   with Pool() as pool:
       print(*pool.map(double, ["one", "two", "tree"]))
```

Чтобы заработал пример с stdlib multiprocessing, необходимо `double` функцию сделать pickable, к примеру, поместив её в отдельный модуль (см.
[Jupyter notebook never finishes processing using multiprocessing (Python 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47313732/4279)):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from multiprocessing import Pool, set_start_method 
from mp_functions import double

if __name__ == "__main__":
   with Pool() as pool:
       print(*pool.map(double, ["one", "two", "tree"]))
```

Первый пример с `multiprocess` вероятно работает так как он использует dill вместо pickle для сериализации.