# multiprocessing в Jupyter

Tags: python, процесс, jupyter-notebook, pool

Помогите , пожалуйста, включить multiprocessing в Jupyter, threading- по понятным причинам мне не особо помогает , просто, для примера оставлю его.

Второй пример в моем сознание должен был мне все ускорить в 4 раза, так как 4 физических ядра на моем ноуте, но что-то пошло не так, вроде, по аналогии с threading, но не работает.

```
import threading
import time

a = []

def func(arg):
    time.sleep(1)
    a.append(arg)



for file in range(100):
    threading.Thread(target=func, args=([1])).start()

time.sleep(2)
print(a)
```

спустя 2 секунды, все работает.

> > > [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

a = []

def func(arg):
    time.sleep(1)
    a.append(arg)



for file in range(4):
    Process(target=func, args=([1])).start()

time.sleep(2)
print(a)
```

> > > []

Comment: связанный вопрос [Работа с пулом процессов приводит к зависанию в Jupyter Notebook](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/852010/23044)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вот так будет работать, из минусов, надо будет внутри вашей функции указать импорт всех используемых модулей так как доступа в пространство с которого происходил запуск не будет, по сути он запускает к ряду несколько интерпретаторов и использует многопоточность виндовс, это видно по процессам.

func - ваша функция, которая должна включать в себя все что будет использоваться

args - аргументы функции, каждый на каждый на запуск.

пример:

```
 args = ['xx1.com', 'xx2.com']
```

после пул запустятся два интерфейса которые будут на двух разных потоках физ. 
 ядрах и 2 функции что-то будут делать по этим адресам параллельно ))

```
    from multiprocess import Pool #! pip install multiprocess

    with Pool() as pool:
            peaks_rates = pool.map(func, args)
```